# What are some common strategies to prove that two geometric objects are homeomorphic except directly finding the continuous map?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

What are some common strategies to prove homeomorphism except directly finding the continuous map?

For example, how to prove that $n$ smooth (n-1) dimensional "surfaces", characterized by $x_i:\mathbb R^{n-1}\to\mathbb R$, $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_n)\mapsto x_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_n)$, in $\mathbb R^n$, that intersect at unique point $p_1$, is homeomorphic to another $n$ surfaces (defined in the same manner) that intersect at unique point $p_2$?

For a simpler example, how to prove that a "cross" characterized by two lines, $x=0 \lor y=0$, is homeomorphic to anther cross characterized by $y=x \lor x=-y$?

Comment: By "prove homomorphism", do you mean "prove homeomorphism"?  And by "prove homeomorphism", do you mean "prove that two manifolds are homeomorphic"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, I changed my expressions

Comment: 1-manifolds and  compact 2-manifolds have a nice classification up to diffeomorphism, so you need to check few  properties (euler characteristic of the surface and boundary component for surfaces or boundary/compactness for 1-manifolds). But for n-manifolds is not so simple.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Thanks Prof Warlock, would you mind to give me one or two notes/books/papers for me to dig in?

Comment: No Prof. thanks I'm just a Sorceror. You can find the classification of 1-manifolds in appendix of  Milnor's "Topology from a differentiable view point". The classification of closed surfaces can be found in many books for example Munkres' Topology chapter 12.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Thanks again mathemagician. Any clues for higher dimensions? Is this problem as hard as the Poincare Conj?

Comment: @HighGPA No, it is harder, as in there is no solution to the problem. There is no general method (as in "algorithm") that can tell you whether two manifolds are homeomorphic. Or even of the same homotopy type. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_manifolds This is related to the unsolvability of the word problem for groups.